# How to disable FavIcon.ico

Tags: html, jsp, aem, favicon

I have two websites hosted on AEM or cq5 with two diffrent domains. The new domain also displays the same favicon. I'm trying to delete that in head.jsp of template. But it still displays.

Even though I delete in both the templates it doesn't delete. I cleared the cache too. Is there a way to delete it?

Comment: Because of your track record of not accepting answers I doubt you'll get any responses. Good luck!

Comment: Yep, losing my interest in answering AEM posts over here... Adobe forums are more well moderated and helpful in this regard. No offence to SO

Answer (score 3):

Seems this isn't the first time I've had to do this. So posting for the next time either of us look ;)
As a work-around

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
```

solves the 404 error

Comment: Note: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) say: "The _shortcut_ link type is often seen before _icon_, but this link type is non-conforming, ignored and web authors must not use it anymore."

Comment: @DonReba thx yes so what worked for me is `<link rel="icon" href="#" />`

Comment: That will cause 2x server load.

Comment: @user1133275 Can you elaborate?

Comment: @CharlesWood Browser will load html page second time instead of favicon.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Blank Favicon.That will override the default favicon.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem basically you need to:

- Delete the root/server favicon check if it exists, this is usually
  automatically picked for all your site/s
- Explicitly point a specific favicon for all sites as below:

  link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"

This should fix it after clearing you cache/browser.

Sample my server has multiple test webapps with different favicon:

- http://tomcat-alkathirikhalid.rhcloud.com/itrainexam/

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it